# If I like a Reddit video, it should be automatically posted as a native video to Facebook-Pages and Twitter with help of IFTTT

Tags: twitter, facebook-pages, if-this-then-that

How can I create the following applet using IFTTT:

If I like a Reddit video, it should be automatically posted as a native video to Facebook Pages and Twitter.
The same should apply for an album. I am able to do it for a single image, but it's not working for an album.